# T-SQL Group By and Sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am aware of what the problem is with my query, but am really struggling to find a solution here.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a992e/1)**

I guess I'm not even really sure how to ask this. What I'm trying to achieve sum all tracking numbers for a date range grouped by branch, but (and this is the kicker) include **any** other records in the sum that have the same tracking number. I thought of doing something like this, but of course SQL Server doesn't like this because I can't have a subquery in an aggregate function.

`MAX((select SUM(demo.NegotiatedRate) where #demo.Tracking = demo2.Tracking)) as NegotiatedRate`

Here is the query I have so far if anyone doesnt want to click the SQL Fiddle link

```
select     demo.Branch, 
           SUM(demo.NegotiatedRate) as NegotiatedRate,
           SUM(demo2.BillRate) as BillRate
from       demo
join       demo2 on demo2.Tracking = demo.Tracking
where      demo.ShipDate = '2014-05-01'
group by   demo.Branch
```

**Expected Output**

The output that I am trying to achieve would look something like this. The `GH6` negotiated rate and bill rate should match even though one of the `GH6` entries falls outside of desired date range.

```
Branch    NegotiatedRate    BillRate
GH4       50                50
GH6       25                25
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that when it doesn't meet you WHERE criteria?

Comment: I was tasked with including it because it's an adjustment, but the accounting guys want to see the totals per tracking number for their date range selected, even if there are other adjustments outside of their selected date ranges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pre-project the overall (non date-range bound, unfiltered) totals in a separate derived table or cte and then join back to it:

```
WITH totals AS
(
  SELECT demo.Tracking,
     SUM(demo.NegotiatedRate) as NegotiatedRate
  from       demo
  group by   demo.Tracking
)
select     demo.Branch, 
           MIN(totals.NegotiatedRate) as NegotiatedRate,
           SUM(demo2.BillRate) as BillRate
from       demo
join       demo2 on demo2.Tracking = demo.Tracking
join       totals on totals.Tracking = demo.Tracking
where      demo.ShipDate = '2014-05-01'
group by   demo.Branch;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a992e/18)

Given that there should only be one `NegotiatedRate` per tracking, you can circumvent the need to add the summed `totals.NegotiatedRate` to the outer query by applying an aggregate (I've used `MIN`), although this is just to pacify Sql.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

As a bit of a simpler answer, you can do something like:

```
SELECT     demo.Branch, 
           SUM(demo.NegotiatedRate) AS NegotiatedRate,
           demo2.BillRate
FROM       demo
JOIN       demo2 on demo2.Tracking = demo.Tracking
WHERE      demo.Tracking IN
           (
               SELECT Tracking
               FROM demo
               WHERE ShipDate = '2014-05-01'
           )
GROUP BY   demo.Branch, demo2.BillRate
```

As I understand it, you get all the tracking numbers you want in a certain date range, then get all the information from those tracking numbers, no matter the date range. Then groups them by the Branch and BillRate, both of which should be one value for each tracking number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to include all rows when one of the dates is the selected date.  If this is correct, then you want the logic in the `having` clause, not in the `where` clause:

```
select     demo.Branch, 
           SUM(demo.NegotiatedRate) as NegotiatedRate,
           SUM(demo2.BillRate) as BillRate
from       demo
join       demo2 on demo2.Tracking = demo.Tracking
group by   demo.Branch
having sum(case when demo.ShipDate = '2014-05-01' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: This is close, however this returns branch `GH6` BillRate as 50 instead of 25

Comment: @mituw16, isn't that what you are asking for with your statement, ***"include the second item in the demo table in the sum() even though it falls outside of the date range"***?

Comment: @Linger My head is spinning with this one. I guess I'm not even really sure how to ask this. What I'm trying to achieve sum all tracking numbers for a date range group by branch, but (and this is the kicker) include **any** other records in the sum that have the same tracking number. Does that make sense?